# Render elementReference in parents view

Tags: angular

So I have this:

Parent component:

```html
<child-component></child-component>

<!-- I want to render child component reference here -->
<ng-template #renderHereRef></ng-template>
```

Child component:

```html
<ng-template #childRef>
    <p>Content</p>
</ng-template>
```

And I was wondering if there is a way to render #childRef in parents component #renderHereRef. Maybe passing the #renderHereRef to child component or maybe outputing #childRef to the parents component, I dont know. I have been reading angular docs but i can't make it work.

Thank u so much.

Comment: Doesn't ng-content or dynamic components fulfill your requirements?

Comment: No, i simplified at maximum the example to manifest what i want but it doesnt manifest why I want it.  I have a tabs component and I want to render the content of the tab in other component.

Comment: But that's exactly what ng-content does, you could still have your parent component with a ContentChildren property, you loop through your childrens to set the tabs names and the content is displayed where your ng-content is, you just need the logic to which tab is currently selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i think i got it.

I have made it work as follows:

*parent.component.html:*

```html
<child-component #child></child-component>

<!-- I want to render child component reference here -->
<ng-template *ngIf="childComponent" [ngTemplateOutlet]="childRef"></ng-template>
```

*parent.component.ts:*

```js
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('child') childComponent: ChildComponent;
    childRef: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.childRef = this.childComponent.childRef;
    }
}
```

*child.component.html:*

```html
<ng-template #childRef>
    <p>Content</p>
</ng-template>
```

*child.component.ts:*

```js
export class ChildComponent {
    @ViewChild('childRef') childRef: ElementRef;
}
```